# Facebook iOS API: how to get public profile URL

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, fbsdk

I'm using `FBSDK` to get basic information about the user like so:

```
[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me"
                                   parameters:@{@"fields" : @"id, about, birthday, email, first_name,last_name, link, middle_name, name, name_format, picture"}
                                   HTTPMethod:@"GET"]
 startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
     if ([error.userInfo[FBSDKGraphRequestErrorGraphErrorCode] isEqual:@200]) {

         NSLog(@"error getting profile info");


     } else {

         NSLog(@"success getting facebook profile %@", result);

     }
 }];
```

however, the `link` field returns a value like this: `https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/283581333995846/` when I open this link in a browser it asks me to login to Facebook before viewing this profile, but when I open another browser (on my desktop computer) and log in to this profile, the link would be `https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100012619704737` and if I give this link to anyone they can open it without having to login to Facebook to view the profile.

my questions are:

1. what does this number represent: 100012619704737 ?
2. how to get the Facebook profile url (which is: `https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100012619704737`) that can be opened on a browser without having to login to Facebook ?

p.s. both numbers above have been changed for privacy reasons

Answer (score 1):

The number represents the "real" profile ID of the user. You're not supposed to be able to convert an app scoped id to a real one. There may be "hacks" though.

If you need to link your app user to a Facebook profile, use the `app_scoped_user_id` link and let the user log in.